# Augmented Reality on Mobile phones

Tags: android, air, augmented-reality, papervision3d, flash-cs5

I am interested in implementing an Augmented Reality application for mobile phones using Adobe Flash Platform. 
Can you please let me know if any sources is available for me to find out how to start?

I'm not sure what software I need to use to implement AR but as I can understand I need:

**ARToolKit Marker Generator** to create the marker matching with the 3D image, then **FLARToolKit** to analyze the image from the marker and **Papervision3D** to create an object that shares that same space with the marker.

Can you please let me know if what I wrote is correct and advise me how to start the implementation on Adobe Flash platform?

Thank you

Comment: i retaged  your question on android as you are not specific to which platform you wish to develop, if thats is not correct please do the pertinent modifications to the questions tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Carlos mentions, you need to be specific about the platform.

If you're developing for windows/osx and want to target the browser, then use flash/actionscript 3.0.
For easy setup, I recommend having a look at **FLARManager**.
If speed is essential, I would suggest using the **FLARToolkit's Alchemy Branch**,
and **Away3DLite** for 3D rendering.

*Note:* The Alchemy branch currently
only supports single markers. Use the default branch for multiple markers.

Find more details on the above mentioned and examples on AR in actionscript on the [disturb media wiki](http://disturbmedia.com/wiki/index.php?title=Actionscript#Augmented_Reality) entry.

The FLARToolkit uses quite a few resources. You need a bit of tuning to get smooth results on win/osx. On android/iphone flash runs slower than on a desktop/laptop when you package it with air 2.5 for android/iphone packager. If you add AR processing and 3D rendering, I imagine it will be tricky to get something responsive.

If you want to develop an AR app for Android I recommend having a look at [Qualcomm's AR SDK](https://ar.qualcomm.com/qdevnet/sdk).

Comment: I would like to create an AR app for Android using Adobe Air. I'm very confused of what i need in order to do it on Adobe Air. However im not sure if that is possible, and if yes then what programs it needed to be compined in order to develop the application.

I read many articles but i'm still confused and sorry that my questions are not clear. I hope somebody with more knowledge can help and advice me.

Thank you

Comment: @Apollon1954 I would recommend using native code for apps where speed is critical. Still, if you need to use AIR/actionscript, start step by step: If you're using Flash CS5, download the AIR for Android extension(http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashpro_extensionforair/) - also checkout the release notes and forum. 2. Have a look at the AIR for Android video tutorials on gotoandlearn (http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=123 , http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=124 ). 3.  Once you're confident on how to access the camera through AIR for Android, start playing with FLARToolkit.

Comment: @Apollon1954 Download and compile the samples that come with FLARManager and the ones that come with the FLARAlchemy+Away3DLite and compare the two for speed. As mentioned in the answer, links to those are on the wiki

Comment: Dear George.. i have watched the videos and i can say that are very clear. The only problem is that Adobe Air for Android doesn't exist to the page anymore and it's not able to find it anywhere. Once i manage to find it and work with it the videos will be very useful.

Comment: @Apollon1954 do you mean this ? http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashpro_extensionforair.html

Comment: @Geoege Profenza Thank you very muck for your reply. In the video one that u advice me to watch he shows a website for Android Developer Prelease on (06:32) showing some forums,documentation of how to develop Air applications for androi. The main problem is that he download a software called "AIR for Android Builds". Can you please let me know how can i find this software in order to continue .

Comment: and i will also need an other one software the "AIR for Android Extension for Flash CS5" Thank you.

Comment: @Apollon1954 AIR for Android is now in in the Android Marketplace. Unfortunately, the Prerelease is now closed, so you can not register and download the .apk from there.  As I mentioned before, the CS5 extension is here: http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashpro_extensionforair.html, there's a checkbox you needed to tick, or direct link: http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashpro_extensionforair/flashpro_extensionforair_p2_112210.zxp

Comment: yeah but what about the "Air for Android build" and "AIR for Android Extension for Flash CS5". I need those two to continue and that what i cant find

Comment: @George Profenza  Sorry about asking the same thing again and again but i really want to start im so excited and i can't find this softwares to be able to it..

Comment: @Apollon1954 "Air for Android build" = AIR for Android...the APK file you get from Android Market...actually if you try to download an app build with AIR for android is should lead you to AIR in case it isn't already installed. Here's a tiny list (http://www.webkitchen.be/2010/10/08/got-air-for-android-try-these-games/) , some are free. AIR for Android Extension for Flash CS = http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashpro_extensionforair/flashpro_extensionforair_p2_112210.zxp ...Did you download the file and run it ? It should open with with the CS5 Extension Manager.

Comment: @George Profenza I'm trying to install it but it gining me the following message You do not have the approprieate permissiong required to perform this operation. Contact your system administrato to obtain permission."

Comment: @Apollon1954 Sounds like a windows user/permissions issue. Have a look online: http://tinyurl.com/22s2uja

Comment: @George Profenza Sorry to bother you again can you please help me where to find "download Air for android builds" to download the required softwares showing on the video (http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=123) on 7:07 minutes