# Mobile Augmented Reality

Tags: ios, mobile, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, air-native-extension

I need to create a mobile app which will ideally

- work on both android and ios
- support multimarker detection (detect 3 markers)
- support multimarker detection of the same image
- use natural photo style markers (not old black block style markers such as Flarmanager)
- ideally using ANE and Air (as have never developed natively or used
  Unity3D)

I noticed the following post but being 2 years ago, is probably out of date.
[Augmented Reality on Mobile phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175113/augmented-reality-on-mobile-phones)

I have been looking into 
http://www.in2ar.com/ which seems to almost do what I need, however having spoken to one of their developers found they don't support multimarker detection of the same image. Was impressed with the speed of their support though.

Have now started looking into Qualcomms solution Vuforia https://developer.vuforia.com/, and am going to look into trying to prototype something using this (have also read that the detection is better using this library?), have asked on their forum whether multimarker support of the same image is supported, not had a response at the time of writing this though.
https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/vuforia-sdk/does-vulforia-support-multimarker-tracking-copies-same-marker. Also wondering if going with this solution what sort of learning curve I can expect learning Unity.

If anyone has any advice or pointers?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully used the Vuforia AR SDK with Unity 3D to build a tablet application that was presented at last year's Mobile World Congress in Barcelona. The tablet was running Android but, as you may know, porting an application/game in Unity3D to a new platform is a breeze. Photorealistic markers are nicely supported by the framework, provided that the picture you use as a marker has a high degree of fine detail (avoid pictures with large areas of a single flat color, for example). In any case, the Qualcomm's marker generator online tool will analyze and rate your image according to how it will perform in realtime tracking.

About multimarker capabilities, I have not tested myself, but the Unity3D plugin includes a QCarBehavior class that exports the following property: "max simultaneous image targets" (an "image target" is the Unity3D entity that represents your AR marker). I don't know if there are additional license restrictions or any other limitations, but the Vuforia SDK seems to be adequate for your purpose.

Comment: ok cheers, will have a play :)

Comment: @Daniel Martín ,I am looking to create just a single marker for ma app.Can you help me , how can I create it which will be used to play video locally ? I am able to run the demo app successfully with the markers provided by Vuforia.Is there any tutorial for markers ?